# Get sum of a column into a "val" (variable)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aggregation

I'm performing aggregation in a dataframe for percentage calculation. I need to store the sum of each column in a separate variable and I can use this in division to calculate the percentage

```
val sumOfCol1 = df.agg(round(sum("col1"),2))
```

This code gives the sum but it will be stored as a dataframe object and it cannot be used for division. The type is:

```
sumOfCol1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [round(sum(col1), 2): double]
```

How can I store it as a constant or double value so that I can use it in later stage of the aggregations?

Comment: `val sum: Long = df.agg(round(sum("col1"),2)).as[Long].first`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the actual value in a dataframe as a `Double` you need to collect the dataframe to the driver using `collect`. The function will return an array with all the rows, see the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#collect--).

Since you have a dataframe it will contain `Row` objects and you have to use `getAs` to access the actual underlying values. A more intuitive way would be to first convert to a dataset and then collect:

```
val sumOfCol1 = df.agg(round(sum("col1"),2)).as[Double].collect()(0)
```

In this case since you only want a single value, you can also use the `first` method:

```
val sumOfCol1 = df.agg(round(sum("col1"),2)).as[Double].first
```

Answer (score 0):

First let's create a data frame:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val schema = List(
  StructField("col1", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("col2", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("col3", IntegerType, true)
)

val data=Seq(Row(10,100,1000),Row(20,200,2000),Row(30,300,3000))


val df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data),StructType(schema))
df.show()

+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|  10| 100|1000|
|  20| 200|2000|
|  30| 300|3000|
+----+----+----+
```

Now we have the data frame.
We can use pattern matching when assigning values to collect the desired results. Since `df.first()` returns a `Row` object, we can do something like this:

```scala
val cols = df.columns.toList
val sums = cols.map(c => round(sum(c),2).cast("double"))

val Row(sumCol1: Double, sumCol2: Double, sumCol3: Double) = df.groupBy().agg(sums.head, sums.tail:_*).first()

sumCol1: Double = 60.0
sumCol2: Double = 600.0
sumCol3: Double = 6000.0
```